# capture screen output in addition to viewing it in real time

Tags: php

in php ob_start buffers the screen output and saves to a variable.

Is there a way to simultaneously display screen output as usual and also log it into a file in real time without using buffering functions?

(have a script which sometimes crashes and would like to see all the error messages and also store them to a file for when it runs by a cron job)

Comment: It has nothing to do with 'real screen output' which only happens on the 'client'. Do you mean 'consequences of using output buffering'? Without buffering see: [outcontrol - buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php), any PHP output is sent over the network immediately to the client. Otherwise the server stores the output until it is 'flushed' for whatever reason ('flush', 'buffer full', 'end of script' etc. How it looks on the client is due to so many other factors such as CSS, Themes, Browser and O/S etc.

Comment: Don't use `echo` or `print` directly. Wrap it into something like `print_line($string)` or whatever and track the output there.

Comment: @hek2mgl print_line is a php function?

Comment: No I meant you should write a custom function for output and don't use `echo` or `print` directly

Comment: @hek2mgl right but i want to capture the other stuff also like error messages which don't come from echo or print statements

Comment: @user813801 Use a custom error handler? Turn on error reporting and display errors? Tail the error log?